# How to call Java method in SQL ? (note - not Java into SQL, but SQL into Java)

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

How do I call Java method in SQL (note - not SQL into Java, but Java into SQL)?

Context is - One algorithm is already built in Java. At some point, I want to use same algorithm in SQL select query. That's why, wanted you use same Java method in SQL instead of writing same algorithm again in SQL.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Database engine is MS SQL 2017.

Comment: It depends entirely on the database.  Some support externally defined user-defined functions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  - What about MS SQL 2017. I want to use inflator-deflator API of Java. How can I use this API logic in MS SQL 2017 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a Java *method* directly from MS SQL, but you can use [`xp_cmdshell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to run a Java *program*.

I would not recommend it, since the overhead will be huge. Depending on complexity, either implement it in both, or maybe only in SQL, then call SQL procedure from Java.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server supports CLR which in essence allows you to call .NET code from within SQL server. If the algorithm can be easily converted to this language, that might be your best bet. Alternatively, you could write code in CLR to call a web service that then calls your Java code. So yes - technically possible. Advisable?... hard to say without knowing the details of your situation.